# Help in the proof that $SO(n)$ is connected

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

I'm trying to prove that $SO(n)$ is connected in the following way:

> We'll approach by induction. For $n=1$, $SO(1)$ is just $\{\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}\}$, so it's obviously connected. For $n=2$, $SO(2)$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ (this can be verified by hand), and hence connected.
>
> For $n>2$, let $A\in SO(n)$. If $e_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then the first column of $A$ is simply $e_1$. That is, $Ae_1=e_1$. Since $A$ is orthogonal, we conclude that $A^Te_1=A^{-1}e_1=A^{-1}Ae_1=e_1$ and hence $A$ is of the form
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1&0\\
> 0&B
> \end{bmatrix},$$
>   where $B$ is an element of $SO(n-1)$. Induction then yields the result.
>
> Otherwise, consider the plane spanned by $e_1$ and $Ae_1$. Let $\{u_1,u_2\}$ be an orthonormal basis of this plane and let $R_1$ from the plane to itself denote the rotation taking $Ae_1$ to $e_1$.
>
> Extend $\{u_1,u_2\}$ to an orthonormal basis $\{u_1,\dotsc,u_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $U$ be the matrix with columns $u_1,\dotsc,u_n$. Then,
>   $$R=U\begin{bmatrix}
> R_1 & 0\\
> 0 & I_{n-2}
> \end{bmatrix}U^T$$
>   is an element of $SO(n)$. Since $SO(2)$ is connected, there is an path from $R_1$ to $I_2$, which induces a path from $R$ to $I_n$ and thence from $A$ to $RA$.

To end the proof I just need to show that
$$RA=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&B'
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $B'$ is an element of $SO(n-1)$. In this case I could use induction to show a path from $RA$ to $I_n$.

However I can't seem to find why this is the case (that $RA$ has the desired form).

PS: I read all the MSE posts about the connectedness of $SO(n)$ and none of them solved my problem.

Comment: $RA$ is orthogonal and has the correct first column, so the other columns are orthogonal to the first implies...

Comment: But I think you also need a special argument for the case $A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}$ where $B$ is an orthogonal matrix with determinant $-1$.

Comment: $RA$ is orthogonal since it is the product of orthogonal matrices. To show that it has the correct first column I would have to prove that $RAe_1=e_1$, right? But that does not appear to be trivial to me.

Comment: Didn't you pretty much construct $R$ specifically so that you would have $RAe_1 = e_1$?

Comment: About that special argument, I think you are right. I will think about it.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. (This proof is based on a tip on a book), but I can't seem to prove that $RAe_1=e_1$.

Comment: Without constructing R, you can directly use the path connectedness if SO(2) to create a path between $e_{1}$ and $Ae_{1}$ within your plane. And the rest of the rotation can take place in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, which is (path) Connected due to your induction hypothesis.